# TYPO3 femanager extension error: Class UserBackend does not exist

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm working on a TYPO3 project with a custom extension and I'm trying to set up femanager but I get the following error when I'm trying to use the backend module provided by femanager:

> Class UserBackend does not exist

Does someone know why this error appears and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Which versions of TYPO3 and EXT:femanager do you use? Is your installation composer based? Did you clear all caches in the install tool after the installation of EXT:femanager?

Comment: I am using TYPO3 version 11.5.0 and EXT:femanager version 6.3.1 . Yes it is composer based. I've cleared the caches multiple times and tried reinstalling EXT:femanager.

Comment: EXT:femanager has not been released for TYPO3 v11 yet. So I'd suggest to file your issue here: https://github.com/in2code-de/femanager/issues